# Music controller is located in the middle of the screen instead of bottom

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I faced with the following problem: when I run the app on my device media controller is located in the bottom of the screen. But when I run the app on emulator, I see media controller in the middle of the screen:

[image]

As I think, it happens because I have more songs on my device, so `RecyclerView` fills whole screen and here `RecyclerView` finishes in the middle, so, media controller is shown here. But why controller is connected with `RecyclerView` I don't understand, as I don't place it anywhere. So what's the matter and how can I solve it?